# Method of moments for Gini coefficient

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

$$f_{c_1,c_2}(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{c_1c_2^{c_1}}{x^{1-c_1}}\ \forall x\leq c_2\\0\ \ \ \  \text{elsewere}.\end{cases}$$

I am given the density function above, from which we are are asked to compute the Gini coefficient. That part I got. But then we are asked to "propose a method of moment estimator for the Gini coefficient".

I know how to compute a method of moment with respect to my density function. But I do not understand what it means to propose a method of moments for a coefficient.

I am also asked to compute the maximum likelihood estimator, and I know as a property that in this case, the result is invariant from the $\theta$ chosen, is it the same for the method of moments ?

Comment: What is your result for the Gini coefficient?

Comment: It is a function $G(c_1)$. $c_2$ does not appear in it. $G(c_1)=(2c_1-1)^{-1}$

Comment: There must be some restrictions on the coefficients, $c_1$ and $c_2$.... Anyway, if you're able to estimate $c_1$ using the MM, then this estimator can be plugged into $G$.

Comment: So when I am asked to propose a method of moment estimator for the gini coefficient it means I should apply the method of moments on the density function, yieling therefore a $c_1'$ and a $c_2'$. And then simply input these results into Gini's as $G(c_1')$ ?

Comment: Yes, $\hat{G}=G(\hat{c}_1)$.